# Cut videos and stack them with hstack in ffmpeg at the same time

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two videos that I want to stack with hstack. The videos are not perfectly in sync so I would like to cut a bit from the beginning of one of the videos to get them to sync perfectly. Everything works fine using two concurrent commands:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:18 -i video1.mp4 -ss 00:00:02.000 -c:v libx264 left.mp4
```

followed by

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack output.mp4
```

I'm wondering however if it is possible to do the trimming at the same time as stacking so that ffmpeg doesn't have to encode the cut video twice. This would save a lot of time for me as I will be doing this cutting & merging multiple times.

I tried various ways to achieve this in one single command, but to no avail so I have to turn to the community. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

For a normal MP4 file, it's as simple as

```
ffmpeg -ss 20 -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack output.mp4
```

Comment: Does this work for exact positioning? I read that -ss before the input file is faster doesn't give perfectly accurate results.

Comment: For transcoding, it is accurate. Inaccurate, when streamcopying.

Comment: Unfortunately using this method starts dropping frames:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i set2-left.mp4 -i set2-right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack -t  20 testcombo2.mp4` Gives a single warning: `Past duration 0.999992 too large` And starts dropping a lot of frames: `frame=   50 fps=9.2 q=-1.0 Lsize=     301kB time=00:00:00.42 bitrate=5770.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=45 speed=0.0787x`

Whereas if I first re-encode the files trimming them and then do the hstack, no frames are dropped.

Comment: You have to set an output framerate manually equal to the greater of the `tbr` value of both videos, to avoid dropping.

Comment: Both input videos have the same tbr (119.88) and setting that framerate manually doesn't help. Both videos have the exact same charasteristics: `Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59964 kb/s, 119.88 fps, 119.88 tbr, 120k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)` .. only the bitrate is marginally smaller on the other one (59941 kb/s)